# Sequelize unable to add virtual property to findAll response

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I have two queries which are as follows:

getPosts - models.Posts.findAll({where: userId});

getPost  - models.Post.findByPk(id);

Posts has a virtual property postTemplate which is essentially a value object passed between the front and back end such that:

```
postTemplate: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL
}
```

The API function (it happens to be a GraphQL resolver in this case) appends the virtual property before returning the data.

```
let post = models.Post.findByPk(id);
post.postTemplate = "blah blah blah";
return post;
```

Now, this works. However when I try to do the same with the getPosts (findAll) it doesn't seem to want to append the property.

I've tried this both within loops and via keys to no avail. I believe I'm misunderstanding the way that batches of records are returned.

```
let posts = models.Post.findall();
posts.forEach(async (post) => {
    post.postTemplate = "blah blah blah";
})
return posts; // this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this? I suspect it did not work because it's an async function

```
async function(req, res) {
  let posts = await models.Post.findall();
  posts.forEach((post) => {
      post.postTemplate = "blah blah blah";
  })
  return posts;
}
```

Comment: The forEach had an async on it which I forgot to include. The code I copied is also inside of an async function.